# How to insert date datatype in cayley db?

Tags: gremlin, cayley

I need to insert date value in a node. Something like *creation date* for another node. But in cayley, we could only insert string datatype. I may use the `toString()` and save the date as string. But, while retrieving, I need to filter by giving a date range. How would I possibly do this?

BTW, I'm using gremlin programming language to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Cayley recognizes [schema.org](http://schema.org) data types, thus you can use [DateTime](http://schema.org/DateTime) type for your values:

```
"1990-07-04T17:25:41Z"^^<http://schema.org/DateTime>
```

Later you can use Gizmo to query date ranges:

```
var d = new Date(1900, 1, 1);
g.V().Has("<birthDate>", gt(d)).All()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can store the dates as unix time-stamps? That way, even if you do a string comparison you'll get the correct results.